# How do you grab a value from the scope from a string

Tags: python

```
from module import * # adds 'BlahRenderer', 'FooRenderer', 'BarRenderer', etc.
class MyClass
    def __init__(self, value)
        renderer = "%sRenderer" % value
        self.RendererClass = ????
```

I know this can be done by doing the import inside `__init__` and then doing `locals()[renderer]` but how do I do it if the import is at the top?

Comment: Have you thought of using eval(renderer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `globals()` instead of `locals()`.

Although it may be better that your `module` defines a dictionary or Factory to map each `value` into a Renderer e.g.

```
renderers = {'Blah': BlahRenderer, 'Foo': FooRenderer, ...}
```